# Ahref inside servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, session-cookies, jsp-tags

I'm currently using a tutorial(http://www.java-programming.info/tutorial/pdf/csajsp2/07-Cookies.pdf) to try and enable cookie creation , my servlet is featured in the code below , However I want to add a href or button so that when the user is greeted they can click and be brought to a jsp in my webContent folder , I'm using jsp , eclipse indigo and tomcat 6 , Any tips would really help as adding the href as shown below doesnt work , btw the w3schools link in the code can be disregarded

```
package The_Quiz;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/** Servlet that processes a registration form containing
 *  a user's first name, last name, and email address.
 *  If all the values are present, the servlet displays the
 *  values. If any of the values are missing, the input
 *  form is redisplayed. Either way, the values are put
 *  into cookies so that the input form can use the
 *  previous values.
 *  <p>
 *  From <a href="http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/">the
 *  coreservlets.com tutorials on servlets, JSP, Struts, JSF, Ajax, GWT, and Java</a>.
 */

 public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
 response.setContentType("text/html");
 boolean isMissingValue = false;
 String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
 if (isMissing(firstName)) {
  firstName = "Missing first name";
  isMissingValue = true;
 }
 String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    if (isMissing(lastName)) {
  lastName = "Missing last name";
  isMissingValue = true;
 }
 String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");
 if (isMissing(emailAddress)) {
  emailAddress = "Missing email address";
  isMissingValue = true;
 }
 Cookie c1 = new LongLivedCookie("firstName", firstName);
 response.addCookie(c1);
 String formAddress =
  "The_Quiz.RegistrationForm";
       if (isMissingValue) {
  response.sendRedirect(formAddress);
    } else {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String docType =
    "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
    "Transitional//EN\">\n";
  String title = "Thanks for Registering";
  out.println
    (docType +
     "<HTML>\n" +
     "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
     "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
     "<CENTER>\n" +
     "<H1 ALIGN>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
     "<UL>\n" +
     "  <LI><B>First Name</B>: " +
            firstName + "\n" +
     "</UL>\n" +
     "<a href="Question_1.jsp">Visit W3Schools</a>" +       
     "</CENTER></BODY></HTML>");
     }
   }

  /** Determines if value is null or empty. */

  private boolean isMissing(String param) {
   return((param == null) ||
       (param.trim().equals("")));
        }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sure its something simple just can't get it working

Answer (score 0):

You add a cookie, but you get a request parameter.
You should create `CookieUtilities` according to the example in the book and use `CookieUtilities.getCookieValue`
If you want to get paramaters - you need to send a request parameters in your URL

Answer (score 0):

The creation of cookie should be like this

```
Cookie c = new Cookie('cookiename','value');
```

second thing for formAddress you should specify url like this

```
/RegistrationForm
```

do not give package name.

Yeah and for anchor tag Specify url of jsp in single quotes